# Import only select data from json to powershell

Tags: json, powershell, uri, invoke-command

I want to Import selected data from Json url and so I can convert it to XML.

I am using following code to import.

```
(Invoke-RestMethod -URI "http://www.broadbandmap.gov/broadbandmap/broadband/dec2013/wireline?latitude=29.488412&longitude=-98.550208&format=json").Results.wirelineServices.providerName | Select-Object | Format-Table –AutoSize
```

so I am using `.Results.wirelineServices.providerName` to pull selected columns from one branch/table.

how can I pull data from .`Results.broadbandSource.stateFips` also at same time?

Thanks bunch.

**Json code screenshot.**
[image]

**follow up question**
[image]

Comment: It would be useful to know what format of XML you wanted to export the data in. Do you just want a serialized data structure containing the (single) stateFIPS vlaue and a collection of wirelineServices objects?

Comment: I don't know if I understood your question correctly abt XML. but I would like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>` if I am making any sense. can xml export be customized way I want it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you should separate out your steps a bit:

```powershell
$r = Invoke-RestMethod -URI "http://www.broadbandmap.gov/broadbandmap/broadband/dec2013/wireline?latitude=29.488412&longitude=-98.550208&format=json"

$providers = $r.Results.wirelineServices.providerName
$stateFips = $r.Results.broadbandSource.stateFips
```

Note that in your example, your call to `Select-Object` is redundant (you're not selecting anything, so it's not changing the input object).

Also, a **very important point** about `Format-Table` (and any `Format-` cmdlet) is that those are for *display only* so they should always be the last thing you do, if in fact they're needed at all.

The code I've given gives you the information in objects, which you can then work with, filter or, display as needed. I'm not sure how you wanted to use/display it, but since there are multiple providers and only one stateFips value, I might assume that you would apply the Fips value to each provider. Here's an example of that which uses the `$stateFips` variable we created:

```powershell
$r.Results.wirelineServices | Select-Object providerName,@{Name='stateFips' ; Expression={ $stateFips }}
```

And here's an example that uses only the original result `$r`:

```powershell
$r.Results.wirelineServices | Select-Object providerName,@{Name='stateFips' ; Expression={ $r.Results.broadbandSource.stateFips }}
```

### The `Select-Object` computed column syntax

Note that the second column definition looks a bit wonky. It's actually a hashtable that allows you to specify the name of the column, and an expression (a complete code block) whose return value will be the value of the column. It could be spread over multiple lines like this:

```powershell
$r.Results.wirelineServices | Select-Object providerName,@{
    Name = 'stateFips'
    Expression = { 
        $r.Results.broadbandSource.stateFips 
    }
}
```

Or you could even create the hashtable as a variable first:

```powershell
$computed = @{
    Name = 'stateFips'
    Expression = { 
        $r.Results.broadbandSource.stateFips 
    }
}
$r.Results.wirelineServices | Select-Object providerName,$computed
```

### XML?

@Stephen Connolly's answer reminded me that you wanted to make XML out of this. Let's take the above code and assign it to a variable:

```powershell
$computed = @{
    Name = 'stateFips'
    Expression = { 
        $r.Results.broadbandSource.stateFips 
    }
}
$data = $r.Results.wirelineServices | Select-Object providerName,$computed
```

Because `$data` is still an object and wasn't sent through a `Format-` command, we can still use it!

```powershell
$xml = $data | ConvertTo-Xml -NoTypeInformation
```

As his comment also suggested though, we don't know how you wanted the resultant XML to be formatted.

So here's another approach:

### Forget the JSON

```powershell
$r = Invoke-RestMethod -URI "http://www.broadbandmap.gov/broadbandmap/broadband/dec2013/wireline?latitude=29.488412&longitude=-98.550208&format=xml"
```

Now `$r` contains XML already. You can filter it out and modify it using XPATH. I won't get into that at the moment unless you think that way would work better for you.

Hope this helps, let me know if I've misunderstood what you're trying to do here.

Comment: I wish I could up-vote this more than once. Excellent depth of explanation, and pointing out things like his use of Select and Format-Table incorrectly are great learning points in my opinion.

Comment: @briantist Thanks a lot from me too. You answered all my unasked question, which I wanted to ask and of course what I asked. I haven't tested the XML part but I will try it and if I get stuck I will get back.

Comment: one question, can XML export be customized exactly the way I want?

Comment: Ehh, not really (not with `ConvertTo-Xml` anyway). If it's easier, you could just generate XML in a string and cast it to `[XML]` in powershell. Something like `$xml = [XML]("<providers>" + ($providers | ForEach-Object { "<provider>$_</provider>" }) + "</providers>")` There may be a more object-y way to do it but this could end up being easier.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, I ran into one problem. my JSON file has an array of data. I am having problem with Expression. For e.g I was able to get providername, but the `Name` and `Expression` doesn't come out correct because it is an array. see the image I uploaded, where `playlist = result` and `wireline = asset` & `broadbandsource = content` and we can use `providername` in asset and `stateflips` in content. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want a composite object try something like

```
$results = (Invoke-RestMethod -URI "http://www.broadbandmap.gov/broadbandmap/broadband/dec2013/wireline?latitude=29.488412&longitude=-98.550208&format=json")
$obj = $results.Results.wirelineServices
$obj | add-member -type noteproperty -Name StateFips -Value $($results.Results.broadbandSource.stateFips) -PassThru 
$obj | convertto-xml -as string
```